# Get current fragment from Service

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, intentservice

I'm trying to get the current fragment from a Service but I'm getting null.

Service:

```
MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();
FragmentManager fm= mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("myFragment");
if (currentFragment.isVisible()){
    // send some stuff 
} else {
        // create notification
}
```

Basically I need it to send some values if it's visible or if it's not visible to create a notification. Both are working but when I put my logic in there I get null value for the currentFragment.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if I were you I would move that piece of code to `MainActivity`. Then, there is several design patterns how you could communicate between Activity and Service:

1. Using Intents
2. [Bind to Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)
3. Using Service object itself (Singleton pattern)

In your case, I would choose 2 or 3 options.

Secondly, implement [Observer pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html) there Activity should be `observer` and Service could be `subject`.

Finally, in `onCreate()` method register as to Service as a observer in order to get messages as method calls from service. How to register depends on what option you will choose.

P.S. I think it is obvious that you get no fragments by just creating Activity object because fragments creates on some lifecycle methods which is called by Android OS.

Answer (score 1):

I would first debug by checking all the fragment names:

```
List<Fragment> fragmentList = fragmentManager.getFragments();
Log.d("MyClass", "fragmentList count: " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList) {
    Log.d("MyClass", "fragmentList: " + fragment.getId() + " : "+ fragment.getTag());
}
```

Comment: I get 0 on the count and a nullpoiterexception on For (Fragment fragment : fragmentList)

Comment: So no fragments at all. I would now go back to code the where the fragment is created and just after it is created, check the fragment list.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, Here's how I could do it:

MainActivity:

```
Static Context context;
...
context=this;
```

Service:

```
FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) MainActivity.context).getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("myFragment");
if (currentFragment.isVisible()){
    // send some stuff 
} else {
    // create notification
}
```

Edit1:

With the help of  LordRaydenMK I've just made it easier. Don't know how I didn't remember to do this way sooner.

Fragment:

```
static boolean visible;

OnResume
   visible=true;

OnPause
    visible=false;
```

Service:

```
if (MyFragment.visible()){
    // send some stuff 
} else {
    // create notification
}
```

Comment: don't assign the Activity to a static variable. You can use a static boolean in the activity/fragment and set it to true/false in `onResume/onPause` to check if a activity/fragment is visible. Or check other options mentioned in Robertas Setkus's answer

Comment: You're right! Now I feel dumb... Just did that. Thanks.